# Why does StringReader read '\uffff'?

Tags: c#, input, console, end-of-line

I am writing a language of my own called SPL. It has an Input command which reads input from the `ISplRuntime.Input` property (it is a `TextReader`). All other commands run on this interface because this way I can write different apps with just one library!

I then wrote another console app to test my language. This is my implementation of `ISplRuntime`. Focus on the `Input` and constructor:

```
public class MyRuntime : ISplRuntime {
    protected TextReader reader;
    protected bool stopped;

    public object Current {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual TextReader Input {
        get {
            return reader;
        }
    }

    public object[] Memory {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public TextWriter Output {
        get {
            return Console.Out;
        }
    }

    public bool Stopped {
        get {
            return stopped;
        }

        set {
            stopped = value;
            if (value) {
                Console.WriteLine ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Program has finished");
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowErrorMessage (string error) {
        Console.WriteLine (error);
    }

    public MyRuntime () {
        string s = Console.ReadLine ();
        reader = new StringReader (s);
        stopped = false;
        Memory = new object[20];
    }
}
```

When the runtime is constructed, it asks for input. And use that input to create a `StringReader` and return it in the `Input` property. So every time the input will only be one lline.

Then I write a program in SPL that outputs the input. And that is where the problem is! When I input 1 1 1 1 it prints 1 1 1 and threw a `FormatException`. This is how I read number input:

```
private bool ReadFromInput (ISplRuntime runtime, out int i) {
    char stuffRead = (char)runtime.Input.Peek ();
    if (stuffRead == ' ') {
        i = 0;
        runtime.Input.Read ();
        return true;
    }

    if (char.IsNumber (stuffRead)) {
        string numberString = "";
        while (char.IsNumber (stuffRead)) {
            stuffRead = (char)runtime.Input.Read ();
            numberString += stuffRead;
        }

        i = Convert.ToInt32 (numberString); //This is where the exception occured! (Obviously, because there is no other methods that would throw it)
        return true;
    } else {
        i = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The parameter `runtime` is just the runtime you have just seen. It returns true if it successfully reads a number. And that number is the output parameter `i`.

After using the "Watch" window in Visual Studio, I found out that number string is `"1\uffff"` when the exception is thrown. That's why it throws it! I know (think) that `'\uffff'` is the end of line character. But why would it appear in my input? I know (think) that pressing Ctrl + Z makes a end of line, but I did not! Then I checked `runtime.Input` in the watch window. This is the result:

[image]

I see that there is a field called `_s` and I think that is the string that I told it to read from. See? `_s` doesn't even contain `'\uffff'`, how come it reads it?

P.S. I already know the solution. I just need to change the `while` loop a little and it works. But I want to know *why* does it reads an end of line.

Comment: _pos = 7, _length = 7.  You don't have to press Ctrl+Z to get the end-of-file condition on a StringReader, it runs out of characters by itself.

Comment: @HansPassant So the last character being read is always `'\uffff'`?

Comment: If you read a character and there is no more then there is no last character.  And you'll get -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mistery here - `\uffff` is produced by your code. All you need is to read the documentation and understand what the methods that you call return.

[TextReader.Peek Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.peek(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>   An integer representing the next character to be read, or **-1** if no more characters are available or the reader does not support seeking.

[TextReader.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The next character from the text reader, or **-1** if no more characters are available.

Hope you see the relation between `-1` (`0xffffffff`) and `\uffff`.